# Javascript battleship game - prompt not responding

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to follow along with my javascript book "headfirst javascript programming"....

the assignment is to make a simplified battleship game. It was working until I added more code... Now the prompt is not showing. Im sure im doing something wrong with the curly brackets. I just want the prompt "Ready, aim, fire! (enter a number from 0-6):" to appear when launching the browser and for it to respond to numerical inputs.

Can anyone quickly tell me why im screwing up? thank you! here is my simple code --->>>

```
//declare variables
var location1 = 3;
var location2 = 4;
var location3 = 5;
var guess;
var hits = 0;
var guesses = 0;
var isSunk = false;

//loop
while (isSunk == false) {

//get
    guess = prompt("Ready, aim, fire! (enter a number from 0-6):");
    if (guess < 0 || guess > 6) {
        alert("Please enter a valid cell number!");
    } else {
//add
      guesses = guesses + 1;
//if
        if (guess == location1 || guess == location2 || guess == location 3) {
            alet("HIT!");
            hits = hits + 1;
            if (hits == 3) {
                isSunk = true;
                alert("You sank my battleship!");
            }
        } else {
            alert("MISS");
        }
    }
}

var stats = "You took " + guesses + "guesses to sink the battleship, " +
                "which means your shooting accuracry was " + (3/guesses);
alert(stats);
```

Comment: You have a typo in your if statement, `guess == location 3`, that should be `location3` Always check the Javascript console for errors to help debug.

Comment: What Editor are you using when your coding? Since that error came up when I pasted the code into VSCode. Where you had 1 extra space.

Comment: Thank you Andy! the prompt is now launching and when I add the incorrect values it tells me "MISS"!

Comment: Mellet -- I am using Sublime Text

Comment: I notice the two typos --> "location 3" and "alet" (instead of "alert). Thank you for the speedy response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your lines

```
if (guess == location1 || guess == location2 || guess == location 3) {
```

and

```
alet("HIT!");
```

have errors, a extra space in location3 variable name and missing r from alert, they should be

```
if (guess == location1 || guess == location2 || guess == location3) {
```

and

```
alert("HIT!");
```